# Prevent websites from regaining tab focus in Safari on macOS

Tags: safari, tabs, focus

macOS Safari somehow allows unfocused tabs to regain focus. This can be very annoying as tabs keep changing in the middle of doing something else.

One such example is https://www.kiwi.com
On this flight search website, just search for a flight and on the flight list page leave the tab open, change to another tab and do your thing. In a few minutes, you will see the kiwi.com showing up an in-page JS popup titled with "Get fresh prices" and the that tab will regain focus, regardless of which other tab you are active on.

Considering it's common to search for flights with multiple tabs, you can see how a behaviour like this can be quite annoying. Regardless, a website should not be allowed to modify tab the focus behaviour while inactive.

- Safari Version 17.4 (19618.1.15.11.12)
- macOS 14.4

Everything is up to date but I have the issue at least for a year since switched to Safari, finally it bothered me enough to look for an answer.

Is there a way to stop Safari from allowing the tabs to change focus?